# jquery append() doesn't preserve data or click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append some links with data and a click handler to a containing div.

jQuery 1.4.3

Fails in FireFox 5.0/Chrome 13.0.782, but works in IE9

I first create the element as a jQuery object, then add the data and click handler.  Then I use .append() to append it to the container:

```
var $selector = $('<a href="#" class="x">Test</a>');
$selector.data('testdata', "Test");
$selector.click(function(event) {
   alert('Clicked: ' + $(this).data('testdata'));
   return false;
});

$('#container').append($selector);
```

I see the link added, but when I click on it, the click handler does not fire.

I thought that maybe I needed to do the append first and then add data+click, but that doesn't work either:

```
var $selector = $('<a href="#" class="x">Test</a>');
$('#container').append($selector);

$selector.data('testdata', "Test");
$selector.click(function(event) {
   alert('Clicked: ' + $(this).data('testdata'));
   return false;
});
```

Does append not preserve data and handlers?  It seems that when I .append($selector),  $selector and the newly added DOM object are not one in the same.

Comment: @slolife: Your code as posted works fine.

Comment: @slolife: Even with 1.4.3 this is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pCZUv/

Comment: I don't see any js errors, but it is definitely not working in Chrome or FF. It is part of a bigger page and the code above is an abbreviation, but I put this sample code in my page and it doesn't work.  I cannot, unfortunately, post the whole page. There must be something else going wrong then.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @slolife Does @Andrew Whitaker's link work for you?  I'm confused whether "it is definitely not working in Chrome or FF" applies to your page or his test.

Comment: @Briguy37, yes the link/code works for me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Why the down vote?  This question is a work in progress as I learn what info is needed to pass on to others to possibly determine a cause/answer.  If I have not provided certain information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my page, the problem exists using jQuery 1.4.3 and 1.4.4. But if I upgrade to 1.6.1, the problem goes away and the code works as expected.  At this *particular* point, I am worried about upgrading to 1.6.1.

My other option is to append the element, then requery for it using jquery before adding data and handlers.  That code does work, but obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you using?  Also, which version of JQuery?  This works for me in firefox, ie, and chrome on JQuery version 1.6.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/sjyEx/)'s the test fiddle I was using.

Comment: Updated the question with this info:

jQuery 1.4.3

Fails in FireFox/Chrome, works in IE9

Comment: @slolife Hmmm...too bad jsFiddle doesn't provide testing for JQuery 1.4.3.  However, it works for me in both 1.4.4 and 1.3.2 in both firefox 3.5.15 and Chrome 12.0.742.100, so confused why it would be broken in 1.4.3.  I'd recommend updating to a newer JQuery version if you are sure that's the problem.

Comment: Moving to jQuery 1.6 fixed it, although I am still confused why it worked at some point, then stopped working in FF but still worked in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the append is the cause of your problem. It's because the html you're passing into $() to create your elements is not a simple tag.

According to the documentation of jQuery(html):

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag, such as `$('<img />')` or `$('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript createElement() function.

This quote is from this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

This means that you may get a different element than what you intend because it's dependent on the browser's innerHTML property. You may find it easier if you pass in a simple tag `'<a></a>'` and add other attributes to it as a second argument map to $(html, props).

To get this to work with a simple tag in the $(html, props) call, you would do something like this:

```
var $selector = $('<a></a>', 
    { 
    "class" : "x",
    "href" : "#",
    text : "Test",
    click: function() {
           alert('Clicked: ' + $(this).data('testdata'));
            return false;
        }
    });

$('#container').append($selector);

$selector.data('testdata', "Test data");
```

Comment: It appears that my answer is not necessary. As others have stated, the sample code appears to work across browsers and with jQuery 1.4.3.

Comment: I tried changing the code to do what you suggested and it still did not work.  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, try using `.appendTo()` instead of `.append()`.

It worked for me.